# Grids to make antennas more directional

Tags: rf, antenna, gain, wavelength

I am designing a parabolic antenna for a radar project.

The frequency range I had chosen should be from 0.4 to 1 Ghz, with a gain of about 15 db. This antenna is only for receiving, but I found out that it will be too big to be installed in place.

My goal is to make it cover a very small portion of the sky, so I came up with this idea:

Could I put a grid in front of the antenna in order to filter out radio waves with a low angle of incidence?

Comment: No, that will not work.  What is the beamwidth of your antenna as designed?  Where will the antenna be pointed?

Comment: If you want to cover a very small portion of the sky, you need a narrow beamwidth.  The narrower the beamwidth, the bigger your antenna (that is, the aperture)  needs to be.

Comment: The beamwidth should be about 3 to 2 degrees and will be pointed above the horizon, with a range of 16 km

Comment: I may seem a little bit naive , but could i ask you how specifically wouldn’t that work ? Would all the waves still manage to reach the antenna ?

Comment: Basically, the RF energy will refract around whatever you put there.  If you put something like that right on top of the dish, you no longer have a parabolic reflector.

Comment: So maybe I hadn’t explained myself properly . The grid is to be put between the target and the antenna itself . Not directly on the reflector dish . Anyway now i have a cleaner idea . Thanks

Comment: If the antenna is too big, won't it still be too big with a grid in front of it? There is something I am not getting about the question. I apologize if I am just being dense.

Comment: Some figures to think about:  Gain of 15 dB (assuming dBi) gives a beamwidth of 36 degrees (G=42000/BW1*BW2). A 3 degree beam requires a gain of 37 dBi (same formula). At 0.4 Ghz this requires a dish of about 20 metres diameter (Ae=G*wl^2/4pi).

Comment: Why do you only want to see a small part of the sky? What's going on in the parts you don't want to see? Low angle of incidence? Do you want to reject ground clutter?

Answer (score 3):

> but i found out that it will be too big to be installed in place .

If you want a narrow beamwidth, then size is your friend. The only thing you can do is to use the size you have efficiently.

If you put a grid in front of the antenna, then if it's a small size-limited grid, waves will refract round it. If you have the space available to make the grid do some optical ray-like shielding, then it needs to be many, many wavelengths in size, and you could do better in the space by making a better directional antenna in the first place.

It's a sort of Heisenberg's Uncertainty thing, the antenna size * beamwidth product can't be reduced below a limit, and you can only reach that limit with a good antenna design. Do some research on Fresnel diffraction to see this.

You say that the grid is to be spaced away from the antenna. If you have the length down range available, then building a long Yagi-type antenna would be a way to improve your beamwidth, without increasing the antenna width/height. The problem with a Yagi of course is its narrow bandwidth, not compatible with the OP's 400 M to 1 GHz.

This could be an XY problem. If the requirement for covering a 'small portion of the sky' is not to have a narrow beamwidth *per se*, but to reject a specific interfering signal close to the wanted signal, then there's an option to use a phased array, and to steer a null onto the interferer. That could be done while still having a relatively small array with a large beamwidth.